# Regex also takes index with for loop

Tags: python, regex

The following regex does exactly what I want it to do, except that it also outputs the index as a digit ( I think it's the index). This messes up my output. So how can I tell it not to take the index ?

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("tstfile.xlsx", names=["col1"])

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(index)
    if str(row[0]).split():
        if not re.findall("(.[A-Z]\d+\-\d+)", str(row)):
            for i in re.findall("(\d+)", str(row)):
                print(i)
```

Input data would look like:

```
123, 456
111 * 222
LL123-456
35
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
123
0
456
1
111
2
222
3
35
4
```

The final desired output should be:

```
123
456
111
222
35
```

So only the data that is actually given in as input.

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: Done! I posted the expected result

Comment: Are you sure this is, what you want? What about float numbers like `16.764`? You would get in return two numbers with your strategy.

Comment: where is your input texts cant see them

Comment: Input data is on top. I changed it to 'Input Data' for you. And I don't need to deal with floats now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
for row in df.values.astype(str):
    for word in row:
        if not re.findall("(.[A-Z]\d+\-\d+)", word):
            for num in re.findall("(\d+)", word):
                print(num)
```

Alternatively, here is a one liner that converts the dataframe values into a string and uses the `re.findall` method to extract the numbers as strings. Words that start with upper case letters and contain a minus sign are excluded.

```
all_numbers = re.findall(r'(\d+)', ' '.join([j for i in df.values.astype(str) for j in i if not re.search(r'[A-Z].+\-', j)]))
for item in all_numbers:
    print(item)
```

If you need integer numbers instead of strings, you can convert the list into a generator with

```
all_integers = map(int, all_numbers)
for i in all_integers:
    print(i)
```

But remember, that generators can only be used once.

Comment: cool that it works, but what about the line: `if not re.findall("(.[A-Z]\d+\-\d+)", str(row)):`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the code. One of the input lines is: `LL123-456`. The following would solve it I guess, but then it puts every answer in a list, which is not what I want:

`for i in df.values.astype(str):
    if not re.findall("(.[A-Z]\d+\-\d+)", str(i)):
        print(re.findall(r'(\d+)', str(i)))`

Comment: Yes those that also contain "-" in between

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
>>> data = """123, 456
... 111 * 222
... LL123-456
... 35"""
>>> data = data.replace(',', '')
>>> data = data.split()
>>> x = [int(i) for i in data if i.isdigit()]
>>> print(x)
```

The output is

```
[123, 456, 111, 222, 35]
```

Comment: You disregarded the pandas dataframe completely. If I had a string it would have been another story.

Comment: Yes, you are right @mr Pi. I'll try to attempt the solution.